# Download file from remote http server with user credentials through Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm trying to download remote file from chef recipe. I can download file using below command if the server does not require username and password.

`remote_file "/destination-folder/large-file.tar.gz" do
   source "http://www.example.org/large-file.tar.gz`

but my server require username and password to download the file.

how can I include username and password into above chef code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source 'https://username:password@www.example.org/whatever'`, and don't forget `sensitive true` too.